# Cycle of births and deaths

Tags: karma, moksha

Where is the first historical reference of the cycle of existence,  according to the scriptures ?

Comment: .Nice question. I had the same doubt in my mind

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What is the life cycle of a soul (atma) in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3568/277)

Comment: @Pandya , not really, It takes some sources, but it doesn’t specify where for the first time this topic is discussed. Vedas? Upanishads? B.Gita? i am asking where is found historically (chronologically)  in any text.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14176/661 Clear mentioning in Yajurveda, Samaveda

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Hindu_texts Timeline

Comment: @hanugm that’s something like i was searching about.

Comment: @LuckyPashu Yeah, although there may be an implicit mention in Rigveda, the clear mentioning can be found in Samaveda, which is believed to be the second oldest Hindu Scripture.

Comment: @hanugm if you can post a complete answer, for reference , we’ll avoid a duplicate and will be also useful (other than for the boon)

Comment:  now is much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [timeline of Hindu texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Hindu_texts), **based on (historical) dating**:

The oldest scripture still extant is [Rig Veda Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigveda#Dating), whose composition is usually dated to roughly between 1800 – 1100 BCE. There is a [debate](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21502/is-reincarnation-or-rebirth-mentioned-in-the-vedas-samhitas) on whether there is a mention of multiple rebirths in Rig Veda Samhita. If we consider the implicit mentioning, then Rig Veda is the first scripture that talks about multiple rebirths.

The next older scripture is [Sama Veda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaveda), whose composition is usually dated (roughly) between 1200 - 800 BCE. It has [clear mentioning about multiple rebirths](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14176/661).

So, it is clear that the first reference of multiple rebirths is up to the interpretation.But the first clear and direct reference of multiple rebirths is as early as 1200 - 800 BCE.

It is also important to note that there is [no absolute dating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaveda#Dating_and_historical_context) for Vedas.